# Accepting your own answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Why does MSE allows accepting your own answers on your question?

As I cannot upvote my own post, I think accepting your own answer should also be prohibited or there should be an option that if 5 or more people rate it as acceptable then and only then it should become acceptable

Comment: X posts a question. Y leaves a hint. With the aid of the hint, X figures out how to answer the question, posts an answer, and accepts it. This is a good thing, and should be encouraged!

Comment: @GerryMyerson [Case in point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401547/solving-linear-differential-equations). Incidentally, the edits by  to both question and answer by [Chiranjeev](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/171345/chiranjeev) are utterly unnecessary. Just sayin'...

Comment: It should be noted that accepting one's own answer basically only puts a green checkmark next to an answer and marks the question as having an accepted answer - it doesn't raise its position on the list nor give reputation.

Comment: In addition to everything mentioned, accepting your own answer aids people who ask the same or slightly different than your question in the future to have a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 13):

Acceptance expresses the preference of the author of the question. This is the only purpose of the checkmark; if the questioner happens to prefer their own answer, it's their business. Artificial barriers around expressing their preference would make the checkmark less meaningful.

It should be noted that one does not get any reputation for accepting own answer.

Votes, on the other hand, are meant to be some (very rough) measurement of the  usefulness of the post. Allowing users to rate own posts as useful / not useful wouldn't make this signal any more meaningful: of course everyone considers their answers useful, otherwise why write them?