# Accepting own answer if there are other, good answers that don't answer the question as intented.

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

I recently posted the following reference request: [click](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205414/genus-degree-formula-for-curves-over-arbitrary-fields-and-a-reference-request/4206338?noredirect=1#comment8731265_4206338)

The question got two very good answers and both answeres made an effort to explain things well. But, in the question I asked for a reference of an explicit mentioning of a certain formula and neither of them could provide such a reference.

I was going to accept one of these answers (because it might be good enough) but then I found a reference that contained exactly what I was looking for. I accepted my own answer because it contains exactly what I said in the question I would accept as an answer.

Is this behaviour correct? I feel like I'm not doing justice to the well intended effort others made to answer my question.

On the other hand, my question said explicitly what I would accept and the only answer that satisfies this is my own. For people that have the same question in the future, wouldn't it be best to see that the actual solution to the question (namely a reference, that contains the formula), is the accepted answer?

Thanks to everyone helping me clarify this. I'm still relatively new to (being active on) this site and never got into a situation were I had to accept my own answer before.

Comment: I think what you did is fine - it means that future users will get a reference, which is brilliant. Maybe your answer there could say some of what you said here though, e.g. showing gratitude towards the other answers - "The other answers are brilliant and I found them super useful. I was going to accept one, but then I found a reference that contained... etc. etc."

Comment: I did as you advised. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes your behaviour is right. You can definitely accept your answer. It is allowed and will help future readers to get more knowledge. However if the other answers have helped you do upvote them and thank them in comments. It should be noted that one does not get any reputation for accepting own answer.

Refer these links for more examples-

[Accepting your own answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21221/876009)

https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16947